# Error 503 while scraping cdiscount (scrapy) Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I've made a spider which work to collect data on cdiscount website. However, each time I scrape more than 320 pages of a category, I have the 503 error and the spider close.

How to deal with that problem ? I've tried changing user agent and using a proxy pool like this :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CdiscountSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.proxy_pool = ['49.236.220.238:52840',  '181.112.41.50:33381', '50.235.111.161:45126']

(...)

       request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents) #on accède au contenu des catégories
       request.meta["proxy"] = random.choice(self.proxy_pool)
       yield request
```

but it didn't work. Please, any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: do you really have `#` sign in front of those lines? that makes that line as COMMENT, means that line is never executed

Comment: I know ^^ I just disabled it x) I'm gonna edit as it can be confusing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a download middleware that keeps retrying with new proxy the URLs that have `503` response until they are successfully scraped

create a file named `custom_middleware.py`

```
import random
import logging

class CustomMiddleware(object):

    proxy_pool = ['49.236.220.238:52840',  '181.112.41.50:33381', '50.235.111.161:45126']

    def process_request(self, request, spider):

        request.meta['proxy'] = “http://“ + random.choice(self.proxy_pool)


    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

        if response.status in [503]:
            logging.error("%s found for %s so retrying"%(response.status, response.url))
            req = request.copy()
            req.dont_filter = True
            req.meta['proxy'] =  “http://“ + random.choice(self.proxy_pool)
            return req
        else:
            return response
```

and in your `settings.py` just enable that middleware

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 1,
    'YOUR_PROJECT_PATH.custom_middleware.CustomMiddleware': 200,
}
```

Comment: First thanks a lot for the example ^^ but I've done exactly as you said and I have this error :
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settings'

Comment: I don't have code 503 anymore so thank you :) now its another problem to solve, I've got :
 ERROR: <twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got NoneType>

Must be something else... i'll check this out..

Comment: @Araxide please post complete scrapy logs and I will tell you what’s going on

Comment: @Araxide comment out middleware code in settings.py  and make sure its not happening due to middleware

Comment: I posted it :) Middleware code is this one ?
# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'cdiscount.middlewares.CdiscountSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

Comment: @Araxide no, that is spider middleware, i gave you download middleware code, you can read my answer again to see how you can enable/disable middleware from settings.py

Comment: I saw your logs, i am not sure whats the issue, please disable middleware and see if it happens.

Comment: @Araxide ok now see my updated answer, copy that code once again, and enable middleware again, then update me

Comment: So I just updated, he detects the 503 and retry but with no result (i got the message I posted around 30 times and then I stopped the spider)

Comment: @Araxide hmm, so your code is 100% correct now, it retries url with a new proxy if it gets 503 response code

Comment: @Araxide you should try adding delay between requests, add ‘DOWNLOAD_DELAY=1’ in settings.py file, or buy more proxies. Also please upvote and accept my answer if it helped